# How to change file:// to http:// in angular / ionic when calling external scripts such as the disqus directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to integrate the disqus directive - can be found [here](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/disqus)

I am running into a few issues due to the way my app is set up. There is a line in the script where the embed .js is called like this

`dsq.src = '//' + scope.config.disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';`

This is returning the following error in the console:

`GET file://mywebsitename.disqus.com/embed.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

This is happening because the url is returning as file:// and to fix it needs to be http://

I changed the url directly in the line of code and it works however the script calls further external files and injects them in the dom and these also return as file:// hence I get the same error.

I am sure all this it has to do with the location module within angualr/ionic but don't know how to modify these as I have been using this 2 only a few months now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you opening your app on your machine? I think // URLs need serving from a web server ( which can be running locally ).

Comment: @jedifans I am running on a compiled android app. I understand what you mean but the directive script was build to run like this so not sure.

Comment: The problem is that the script is intentionally leaving out the protocol of the other external files, so that they'll inherit the `http:` or `https:` protocol from the original page. They're designed to be used only from pages that are loaded from a server, not a local file. You need to contact Disqus to see if there's some way to do it with a local file.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks that I know however the directive works on other apps. As per GitHub link

Comment: Are your other apps loaded from a `file://` URL?

Comment: @Barmar I dont have other apps. What I am saying is that this is an angular directive which works for a lot of users who got it.  https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/disqus

Comment: Because they're all using it from apps hosted on a server, not a local file.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean now! They are using angular for webapps not compiled apps...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call it from index.html?
That way it will be part of the Ionic application, and changing the path to it, it should load it.

In index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/disqus.js"></script>
```

And then just call

```
disqus.src = "path/to/disqus.js";
```

Comment: Thats how I am running it but I think @Barmar has a point, its not meant to run on an ionic app..